# Jquery getting two divs to act as one

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, drop-down-menu

I have the following code for my popup menu, the parent link is the top level link.  It causes a popup to show.  Popup fades in and fades out when the mouse enters and exits parent link.

However, I need it to not fade out the popup, if the mouse is over the popup!  At the moment, as soon as the mouse enters the popup it fades it out.  I need both divs to act as one for the hover, if this makes any sense!

```
// Hovering over the parent <li>
ParentLink.hover(
    function()
    {
        Popup.fadeIn(300, function() {
        });
    },
    function()
    {
        Popup.fadeOut(400, function() {
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: You should *nest* the popup inside the parent. That's probably the best and more logical way. Hover will propagate towards the parent so it'll not fire hover-out event when you mouse over onto the popup.

Comment: @Salman thanks, but by design this is quite hard to do unfortunately :(  It looks like refactoring it this way is probably best though

Comment: I'll edit my answer. But normally, this is how the popup menus generally work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should nest the popup inside the parent. This way when you move the mouse from the parent to the popup, the parent will still be in a mouse-over state because popup's mouse-over event is bubbled onto the parent. When the mouse is out of the parent (plus its children), mouse-out event will fire on the parent.

## Edit

If you are not able to (or want to) change the markup, one possibility is to move the elements to the recommended positions using jQuery, like:

```
ParentLink.append(Popup); // moves the Popup element from its current position
                          // and places it as the last child of ParentLink
```

Most probably you'll have to modify your CSS to match the changes so you may want to think first.

Comment: Thank you, I've gone for nested content which seems to be easiest, a lot of CSS issues but getting them sorted out eventually :)

Answer (score 1):

you could unbind the hover-event for the parentlink on completion of the fadein.

```
    Popup.fadeIn(300, function() {
       $(ParentLink).unbind('hover');
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of how to fade out the popup when the mouse isn't over either of them

Comment: you could set a mouseover event for the parentlink and the mouseout event for the parentlink AND the popup.

Comment: U just need to think logically where to put the unbind and hover functions... this u can achieve easily with unbind and hover calling them in appropriate places.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question but a hint how this could work.

Why don't you nest the the 2nd `<div>` into the first one, so the `out` will not occur?

```
<div id="ParentLink">
    <div id="Popup"></div>
</div>
```

Have `#ParentLink { display: relative; }` and `#Popup { display: absolute; }` and you will be fine.

But for those menu's I would always use a nested unordered list structure like this one:

```
<ul id="topLevel">
   <li id="level1item">
      <a href="">Link</a>
      <ul id="subLevel">
          <li>
             <a href="">Link 2</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

As said, unbind the event while you are hover the popup and then re-bind it when you are hovering out :

```
ParentLink.hover(
    handlerIn,
    handlerOut
);

var handlerIn = function()
    {
        Popup.fadeIn(300, popupFadeIn);
    };

var handlerOut = function()
    {
        Popup.fadeOut(400);
    };

var  popupFadeIn = function() {
       $(ParentLink).unbind('hover');
       $(this).mouseleave( function () {
           $(ParentLink).hover(
               handlerIn,
               handlerOut
          );
       });
};
```

btw, I didn't tested this

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
  var inn;
    $('ParentLink').hover(function() {
        inn = false;
        $('p').fadeIn(1000);
    },
    function() {
        $('Popup').bind('mouseenter mousemove',
        function() {
            inn = true;
        }).mouseout(function() {
            inn = false;
        });
        if (!inn) $('Popup').fadeOut(1000);
    });
```